# Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - convert Json output to dataframe

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to get data from Facebook using Graph API; the output data was in json format, i wanted to convert to dataframe. The code works perfectly before, but suddenly today resulted in an error as below

**code**

```
result = AdAccount('act_xxxxxxxx').get_custom_audiences(fields = fields, params = params,)
result
```

The result shown:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAeVG.png)

but as i continue with the following step, it shows error

```
result = [x for x in result]
dat_x = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/facebook_business/utils/api_utils.py:30: UserWarning: Value of type is not be compatible. Expect Type; got <class 'str'>
  warnings.warn(message)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/facebook_business/utils/api_utils.py:30: UserWarning: Value of sub_type is not be compatible. Expect SubType; got <class 'str'>
  warnings.warn(message)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-b2f1af06655d> in <module>()
      2 result = AdAccount('act_xxxxxxx').get_custom_audiences(fields = fields, params = params,)
      3 result
----> 4 result = [x for x in result]
      5 dat_x = pd.DataFrame(result)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/facebook_business/api.py in load_next_page(self)
    831             'summary' not in self.params
    832         ):
--> 833             self.params['summary'] = True
    834 
    835         response_obj = self._api.call(

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't have given it a `params` that is a list. Just a guess though.

Comment: hi fields and params are defined ```fields = ['id','name','data_source','subtype','account_id']
params = {}```

Comment: btw i just found that the output was not json format, but instead facebook_business.api.Cursor

Comment: i see the same issue after upgrading to api v8.0.. The same was working good with v7.0

Comment: Any updates on this ? 
I've ran into the same issue, and only solved it by downgrading to the API v6.

Comment: Note that Facebook had deprecated Marketing API v6 as of 9/30/2020, but now says v6 is "Extended to February 8, 2021", so I think they know there's something screwy. [link] (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/)

Comment: Looks issue in v8.0.0 upgrading to v9.0.0 works for me